# Preferred Method to (Accurately) Get Time From User Input (in UiApp - GAS)

Tags: javascript, time, google-apps-script

UiApp has [`DateBox`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/date-box) and [`DateTimeFormat`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/date-time-format)
 for that Class. However, there is no such thing as `TimePicker` or `TimeBox`, where a user could enter a time in a well-specified manner such as through using Google Forms:

[image]

Forms has different behavior for this Widget in Chrome vs Firefox (I much prefer the Chrome behavior). Anyway, currently I am using a `TextBox` to get time values, where someone would enter a time value in the following manner:

`12:00` or `13:50`, etc. These times would be in the 24-hour clock so that I could create new `Date` objects based on `someDate + " " + startTime`, which would act as the real start time for an event on the Calendar (this is the process I currently use in several of my applications at work). This is obviously unreliable for several reasons.

Ex: If the user entered anything except a valid 24-hour representation in `HH:MM:SS`, Date creation would fail.

I don't want to force my boss to be overly-precautious about how he inputs times into the UI, and I also want to avoid regexing "valid" formats and having the UI do a lot of back-end work (it would be 18 regex tests total, and if any failed I'd have to handle them individually).

So, *the question*: is there an efficient/preferred method of getting *times* in UiApp, either via `TextBox` or some other interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like that ?  Test app [here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwCOcGoX4pbFDXMqK2IDsmuxZSAZMEIcwRKm8KN5yxoyAowqa61/exec) (updated with new version, see edit)

[image]

code below :

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('enter time');
  var frame = app.createVerticalPanel().setStyleAttributes({'border':'solid 1px #AA6','background-color':'#FFD','padding':'15px'});
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('setTime').addCallbackElement(frame);
  var h = app.createListBox().setId('h').setName('h').setStyleAttributes({'margin':'5px'}).addChangeHandler(handler);
  for(var n=0;n<12;n++){h.addItem(Utilities.formatString('%02d', n),n)}
  var m = app.createListBox().setId('m').setName('m').setStyleAttributes({'margin':'5px'}).addChangeHandler(handler);
  for(var n=0;n<60;n++){m.addItem(Utilities.formatString('%02d', n),n)}
  var am = app.createListBox().setId('am').setName('am').setStyleAttributes({'margin':'5px'}).addChangeHandler(handler);
  am.addItem('AM').addItem('PM');
  var date = app.createDateBox().setValue(new Date()).setFormat(UiApp.DateTimeFormat.DATE_LONG).setName('date').addValueChangeHandler(handler);
  var label = app.createHTML('<b>StartTime *</b><br>When your reservation starts').setStyleAttributes({'fontSize':'10pt','font-family':"Arial, sans-serif",'padding-bottom':'10px'});
  var subFrame = app.createHorizontalPanel().setStyleAttributes({'border':'solid 1px #AA6','background-color':'#FFD','padding':'5px'});
  var result = app.createHTML().setId('date').setStyleAttributes({'fontSize':'10pt','font-family':"Arial, sans-serif",'color':'#AA6','padding-top':'20px'})
  .setHTML(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)), Session.getTimeZone(), 'MMM-dd-yyyy    HH:mm'));
  frame.add(date).add(label).add(subFrame).add(result);
  subFrame.add(h).add(m).add(am);
  return app.add(frame);
}

function setTime(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var date = app.getElementById('date')
  var date = new Date(e.parameter.date);
  var am = e.parameter.am
  if(am=='AM'){am=0}else{am=12};
  var h = Number(e.parameter.h)+am;
  var m = Number(e.parameter.m);
  date.setHours(h,m,0,0)
  Logger.log(date);
  app.getElementById('date').setHTML(Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getTimeZone(), 'MMM-dd-yyyy    HH:mm'));
  return app
}
```

---

**EDIT :** here is the wrapped version and a demo with a grid and 10 panels.

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('enter time');
  var grid = app.createGrid(10,2)
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('setTime').addCallbackElement(grid);
  var varName = 'date';
  var htmlString = '<b>StartTime *</b> When your reservation starts'
  for(var idx=0 ; idx<10;idx++){
    var frame = pickDate(idx,varName,htmlString,handler);
    grid.setText(idx, 0, 'test widget '+idx+' in a grid').setWidget(idx,1,frame);
  }
  var result = app.createHTML('<h1>Click any widget</h1>').setId('result');
  return app.add(grid).add(result);
}


/* wrapped version
** takes a var name + index + label string + handler
** as input parameter
** The same handler will be used for every occurrence , the source being identified in the handler function (see code example below)
** and returns a selfcontained widget that you can add to a panel or assign to a grid
** or a flex Table
*/
function pickDate(idx,varName,htmlString,handler){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var frame = app.createVerticalPanel().setStyleAttributes({'border':'solid 1px #AA6','background-color':'#FFD','padding':'1px', 'border-radius':'5px'});
  var h = app.createListBox().setId('h'+idx).setName('h'+idx).setStyleAttributes({'margin':'5px'}).addChangeHandler(handler);
  for(var n=0;n<12;n++){h.addItem(Utilities.formatString('%02d', n),n)}
  var m = app.createListBox().setId('m'+idx).setName('m'+idx).setStyleAttributes({'margin':'5px'}).addChangeHandler(handler);
  for(var n=0;n<60;n++){m.addItem(Utilities.formatString('%02d', n),n)}
  var am = app.createListBox().setId('am'+idx).setName('am'+idx).setStyleAttributes({'margin':'5px'}).addChangeHandler(handler);
  am.addItem('AM').addItem('PM');
  var date = app.createDateBox().setValue(new Date()).setFormat(UiApp.DateTimeFormat.DATE_LONG).setId(varName+idx).setName(varName+idx).addValueChangeHandler(handler);
  var label = app.createHTML(htmlString).setStyleAttributes({'fontSize':'10pt','font-family':"Arial, sans-serif",'padding-bottom':'3px'}).setId('html'+idx);
  var subFrame = app.createHorizontalPanel().setStyleAttributes({'border':'solid 1px #AA6','background-color':'#FFE','padding':'1px', 'border-radius':'4px'});
  frame.add(label).add(date).add(subFrame);
  subFrame.add(h).add(m).add(am);
  return frame;
}

function setTime(e){
//  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var idx = Number(e.parameter.source.replace(/\D+/,''));
  Logger.log('date'+idx+ '  > '+e.parameter['date'+idx]);
  var date = new Date(e.parameter['date'+idx]);
  var am = e.parameter['am'+idx];
  if(am=='AM'){am=0}else{am=12};
  var h = Number(e.parameter['h'+idx])+am;
  var m = Number(e.parameter['m'+idx]);
  date.setHours(h,m,0,0)
  app.getElementById('result').setHTML('<h1>Widget Nr '+idx+' has value '+Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getTimeZone(), 'MMM-dd-yyyy    HH:mm')+'</h1>');
  return app
}
```

Comment: Oh my gosh... this is extremely detailed and wonderful... but I'm wondering if this would be possible to integrate into 18 different 'widgets' (embedded frames I suppose)? For example, I have 9 editing/training sessions that have both start time and end time. Could I (theoretically) wrap this into a function and have it return some kind of `Panel` that would replace what I'm currently using (`TextBox`)?

Comment: short answer : **yes you can** ! (sounds familiar ;) one could write a wrapped version that would take an index as input parameter (to identify var name in handler) and that will return a panel with hours and date. You will also be able to modify it to add a string for the label if necessary.

Comment: Thanks Serge, you're amazing! One other question though - do you think that this would cause a lot of overhead? I worry because I have up to 9 calls to `getEventSeriesById` that take *3-6* seconds total to run, depending on how many there are. I will probably create a "fetching details" label that is shown while the function is running, just to indicate that things are happening. I just don't want my boss to have to wait ~10 seconds to load one project, and I'm getting close to that number by loading <= 9 Calendar Events (an unavoidable operation). Need to optimize! :P

Comment: it could indeed become critical... give it a try, I updated my answer with the wrapped code and updated the demo too.

Comment: btw, even if it works with Firefox don't use it **it's ugly !** This Browser is really getting outdated, they can't follow the race and ignore a big part of the styles ;/ I'm not surprised that Chrome is now the number 1 most used Browser ;)

Comment: Very nice! Once I get the basic data import fully complete, I'll merge this into a 2nd version and see the differences in load times. If making 18 of these 'complex' widgets creates too much overhead, I'll have to scratch the idea for now and work on implementation and performance tuning later - I have a deadline fast approaching to at least get a working version of this application up and running, time input is one of the *lesser* problems. And yes, I agree Firefox is **absolutely** lacking on styles. I use Chrome for work, and I'm about to obliterate Firefox from all my systems! :P

Comment: In any case, I hope a lot of people stumble across this question - This implementation is the best method of getting time values (along with dates even!) in my opinion. I hesitated for a minute before asking this question, because DateJS is always an option for times, but I wanted to avoid using an external library. So once again, thanks!